# 夫に不満を持つ I feel dissatisfied with my husband or husband holds dissatisfaction within himself?

Tags: meaning

> 夫に不満を持つ

Hello, as per the title does this mean:

1 -  I feel dissatisfied with my husband

or

2 - husband holds dissatisfaction within himself?

Comment: What do you know about the particle に that follows the word 夫? What does that particle usually indicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

夫に不満を持つ means "to be dissatisfied with (my/her/the) husband". There is no word that determines the subject or whose husband, so it can mean "I feel dissatisfied with my husband", "She feels dissatisfied with her husband", "She feels dissatisfied with my husband", and so on.

夫**が**不満を持つ would mean "(my/someone's) husband is dissatisfied".